# Problema al intentar ejecutar el comando sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux

Apenas he instalado la distribucion de Linux mint 18.3  y no he instalado ni he movido nada absolutamente nada. Tan solo intento correr el comando `sudo apt-get update` para actualizar los paquetes del sistema y al correr al comando me genera el siguiente problema:

> W: The repository 'cdrom://Linux Mint 18.3 *Sylvia* - Release amd64 20171124 xenial Release' does not have a Release file.N: Data
>   from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore
>   potentially dangerous to use.N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
>   repository creation and user configuration details.E: Failed to fetch
>   cdrom://Linux Mint 18.3 *Sylvia* - Release amd64
>   20171124/dists/xenial/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Please use
>   apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot
>   be used to add new CD-ROMsE: Some index files failed to download. They
>   have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 3):

Edita el fichero `/etc/apt/sources.list` y comenta la linea en la que aparece el cdrom

Deberías tener otras lineas sin comentar de este tipo

```
deb http://site.example.com/distro distribution component1 component2 component3
deb-src http://site.example.com/distro distribution component1 component2 component3
```

Que son las que van a serte de utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Lo que paso es que hiciste una instalacion desde un CD desde el cual se cargaron los repositorios, lo que debes hacer ahora es ejecutar

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Luego moverte has la linea donde dice cdrom y comentarla, para hacerlo debes presionar i y luego #

para salir debes presionar la tecla ESC luego : y luego escribir wq! para guardar los cambios, todo esto debe ser como root

Comment: Si listo muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución "gráfica" sin editar manualmente los ficheros sería usando:

- **lanzador de aplicaciones** -> **Instalar nuevas aplicaciones** (gestor de software)
- En el **gestor de software**, entra en el menu Editar que te abrirá otra ventana de opciones.
- En la nueva ventana de **Origenes del software** dispones de 4 secciones para cambiar el origen de tus paquetes instalados y una sección de mantenimiento (para reparar posibles errores). En tu caso particular debería ser suficiente con desactivar el CDROM de instalación que está en la sección de **repositorios adicionales**

Si tu problema es que no llegas a abrir el entorno gráfico entonces la solución será editar manualmente el fichero *sources.list* que ya te ha indicado anteriormente Kyrie001.